# Access Sibling Class Method

Tags: php, oop, class, visibility, siblings

I'm working on a basic MVC for practice, but I get this error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function run() on a non-object in Router.php on line 5`

What am I doing wrong?

**Core:**

```
<?php

class Core {
    protected $router;
    protected $controller;

    public function run() {
        $this->router =& load_class('Router');
        $this->controller =& load_class('Controller');

        $this->router->run();
    }
}
```

**Router:**

```
class Router extends Core {
    public function run() {
        echo $this->controller->run();
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
class Controller extends Core {
    public function run() {
        return 'controller';
    }
}
```

**Oh, and the load_class function**

```
function &load_class($class_name) {
    $path = ROOT . 'system/classes/' . $class_name . '.php';

    if (file_exists($path)) {
        include_once($path);

        if (class_exists($class_name)) {
            $instance = new $class_name;
            return $instance;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: how are you running the code?

Comment: What does `var_dump($this->controller)` show?

Comment: @Barmar it shows nothing.

Comment: @Raidenace I'm calling $core->run()

Comment: What line is the error happening on?

Comment: can you do a `var_dump($this);` just before `$this->router->run();` and paste what it gives?

Comment: When you substantiate Router (into $this->router) you are creating an instance of the class Router which extends Core. Which has variables $router and $controller in it, so $this (Router class) -> controller (variable) is null, you should `parent::$controller->run();`. This way it refers back to the CORE class where $controller and $router are instances of classes.

Answer (score 2):

If you expand out the extending to see what it actually looks like you will see why it fails:

```
class Core {
    protected $router;
    protected $controller;

    public function run() {
        $this->router =& load_class('Router');
        $this->controller =& load_class('Controller');

        $this->router->run();
    }
}
```

Entending:

```
class Router extends Core {
    public function run() {

        echo $this->controller->run();
    }
}
```

which is **roughly** the same as:

```
class Router {
    protected $router;
    protected $controller;   // <- this is "$this->controller"

    public function run() {

        echo $this->controller->run();
    }
}
```

As you can see $this->controller is a variable so has no methods

So in the extended version you will need to reference the parent class using parent::$controller->run();

Answer (score 0):

I could be off base here, but by extending `Core` in each of these classes, I think you've inadvertently overridden the `run()` method and confused the scope of each class. Have you tried calling `run()` from a separate, non-extended class?